# How to get maximum datetime in the array using dataweave mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb

I have input array is like below

```
   [{"modifiedDate":"2015-07-01T01:00:00.521"},{"modifiedDate":"2018-07-01T03:23:00.654"},{"modifiedDate":"2017-03-14T11:25:35.877"},{"modifiedDate":"2018-06-01T05:23:00.712"}]
```

Out of above input I should get only highest datetime. How can i do it in dataweave

Answer (score 0):

```
(payload orderBy (($.modifiedDate ++ "Z") as :datetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"} as :number {unit: "milliseconds"}))[-1]
```

Each modifiedDate is converted to a datetime (add "Z" as the given dates don't have timezone information, and localdatetime doesn't coerce to number) then to a number of milliseconds, then ordered in ascending order. The [-1] selector takes the last item, which is that with the maximum date.

Output is `{"modifiedDate":"2018-07-01T03:23:00.654"}`